# The basic difference between RSA algorithm and Shor's algorithm

Tags: encryption

i want to have a comprehensive answer to difference between RSA algorithm and shor's algorithm. Can i say Shor's algorithm makes use of quantum algorithm while RSA uses classical?

Comment: While Shor's algorithm is a quantum algorithm, I'd hardly say that qualifies as a *comprehensive* difference between Shor and RSA.

Comment: What's the difference between a bullet and glass?

Answer (score 6):

Shor's algorithm solves a very different problem than RSA. There is pretty much no relation between them other then Shor's algorithm breaks security of RSA. It is like asking the difference between a car and cooking. The question does not make much sense.